# Can't get V8 Monolith to genorate

Tags: shared-libraries, v8

I've been trying to use -v8_monolith in my make files but so far it's not working.

I gotten **v8** code from **google's depot-tools**, then followed every tutorial on the web to try to compile the **shared libs** for **v8**. I'm assuming that the ninja compiler automatically puts the **libs** in to the **arch lib** folder, since no tutorial says to do anything with the files.
*As of rn, I get no errors from the ninja compiler.*

Maybe I got to change something in the **args.gn** to push in to my libs folder. Possably it's trying to push to the wrong location.
this is what it looks like:

```
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
use_custom_libcxx = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
is_component_build = false
v8_static_library = true
```

here is the entire processes from terminal:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=depot_tools:$PATH
mkdir v8
cd v8
fetch v8
gclient sync
tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release
#then this is the point where I manually go to args.gn to edit it
ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
```

I've also tried getting the v8 package from AUR, but does not compile correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> compile the shared libs for v8

In that case, you need `is_component_build = true`. And then you'll have to drop `v8_monolithic`, because that forces a static (i.e. non-shared) library. I don't think `v8_static_library` matters, at least I've never used that.

For the record, we (V8 team) tend to recommend static linking, mostly because of the rate of change to V8's API: any time you update the shared library, you'll have to recompile all programs using it anyway, so there's not a lot of benefit to be had from it being a shared library (but some room for accidental breakage, which a statically linked build avoids).

> puts the libs in to the arch lib folder

I don't know what you mean by "the arch lib folder"; `libv8.so` will be in `out.gn/x64.release/` (or whatever directory you pass to `ninja -C <dir>`). If you want it elsewhere, you'll have to put it elsewhere. Building V8 doesn't touch the rest of your system (there's no `make install`-like target).

> trying to use -v8_monolith in my make files

Once everything else is correct, that'll be `-lv8 -lv8_libbase -lv8_libplatform`, and the corresponding library files will be called `libv8.so`, `libv8_libbase.so`, and `libv8_libplatform.so`.